# Way to move options up and down in a select element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a drop down with few options. I want to select an element and move it up and down. I have tried and up to now I can remove the selected item but I am not sure how to paste it.

Like in my example if I move example 2 and move up the example 1 should come at the end and example 2 should be on the top.

```
$(function () {
    function cutAndPaste(from, to) {

        return $(from + " option:selected").each(function () {
            this.outerHTML;
        }).remove();
    }

    $("#moveup").off("click").on("click", function () {
        cutAndPaste("#sourceSelect", "#destinationSelect");
    });
});
```

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/57f2drgj/

Comment: Why do you use `off()` and then `on()`, and what's the point of your `to` parameter in your `cutAndPaste` function?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6713702/move-item-up-and-down-in-select-using-button

Comment: I may be mistaken, but I don't think `this.outerHTML;` is doing anything at all (meaning that the function you are calling in the `each` statement is pointless)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're moving an element, you don't have to `remove` it first. jQuery's [`insertBefore`](http://api.jquery.com/insertbefore/) and [`insertAfter`](http://api.jquery.com/insertafter) functions will move it.

You can test if the selected option is the first or last by using `.is(':first-child')` and `.is(':last-child')`.  You'll then move it to the end or to the beginning.

**Snippet:**

```js
$('#moveup').click(function() {
  var opt = $('#sourceSelect option:selected');
    
  if(opt.is(':first-child')) {
    opt.insertAfter($('#sourceSelect option:last-child'));
  }
  else {
    opt.insertBefore(opt.prev());
  }
});

$('#movedown').click(function() {
  var opt = $('#sourceSelect option:selected');
  
  if(opt.is(':last-child')) {
    opt.insertBefore($('#sourceSelect option:first-child'));
  }
  else {
    opt.insertAfter(opt.next());
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="sourceSelect" id="sourceSelect" multiple="multiple" size="3">
  <option value="example1">Example1</option>
  <option value="example2">Example2</option>
  <option value="example3">Example3</option>
</select>


<input type="button" name="moveup" id="moveup" value="up" />
<input type="button" name="movedown" id="movedown" value="down" />
```

Answer (score 2):

Something like that?

```js
$(function() {
    $("#moveup").click(function() {
        if($("#sourceSelect").prop("selectedIndex") > 0){
            var selOption = $("#sourceSelect").find(":selected");
            selOption.insertBefore(selOption.prev());
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="sourceSelect" id="sourceSelect" multiple="multiple" size="3">
  <option value="example1">Example1</option>
  <option value="example2">Example2</option>
  <option value="example3">Example3</option>
</select>


<input type="button" name="moveup" id="moveup" value="^" />
```

Comment: This is good, and you don't even need the `if` statement.  If there's no previous sibling, `insertBefore` will leave it in place.

Comment: Thanks :) in the same way you can make 'down' if you want to. Just check that the elected option is not the last one.

Comment: Again, you don't need to bother checking.  Using this code `selOption.insertAfter(selOption.next());`, if you're on the last option, there's no `next` sibling, and `insertAfter` won't do anything.

Comment: thanks @AlexanderDayan but in my case If I am moving example 2 up the example 1 should come at the bottom . it should nt swap between 1 and 2 ??

Comment: same way if you are moving the example3 down it should move to the top by making example 2 at the bottom and example 1 in middle.

Comment: Goood work. . .. !!!