# Move item in <select>

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu

Is there any way to move selected item up or down (to order the items) with jQ?

```
<select name="menu_select" class="form-control" size="10">
    <option value="">opt1</option>
    <option value="">opt2</option>
    <option value="">opt3</option>
</select>

<button>UP!</button>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Move item up and down in select using button](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6713702/move-item-up-and-down-in-select-using-button)

Answer (score 2):

https://jsfiddle.net/refan/axyyqenb/

```
 $("button").on("click", function() {
   var selected = $("#menu_select option:selected");
   var prev = selected.prev();

   selected.after(prev);
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the right way to do it:

```
$("#menu_select option:selected").prependTo("#menu_select");
```

Comment: thx but a little wrong cuz i want to move the item one step up, not to the top)

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
 $("#menu_select option:selected").next().insertBefore("#menu_select option:selected"); 

 $("#menu_select option:selected").prev().insertAfter("#menu_select option:selected");
```

Comment: Please add explanation to improve this answer's quality.